# How to sequentially append one vector from a vector list to one data frame from a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector, append

Consider the following setup

```
vector1 = c(1:3)
vector2 = c(4:6)
vector3 = c(7:9)
vectors = list(vector1, vector2, vector3)

df1 = data.frame("region" = c ("n", "s", "w"), "x" = c (10:12))
df2 = data.frame("region" = c ("n", "s", "w"), "x" = c (13:15))
df3 = data.frame("region" = c ("n", "s", "w"), "x" = c (16:18))
dfs = list (df1, df2, df3)
```

So there is one list with three vectors and one list with three data frames. I need to sequentially append "vector1 from "vectors" as a new column to "df1" from "dfs", "vector2 from "vectors" as a new column to "df2" from "dfs", and so forth.

It can be easily done with:

```
df1$vector1 = vectors [[1]]
```

But things get ugly when you are dealing with a large number of data frames and vectors. Thanks for any direction towards a lapply method, loop method, or anything that can streamline this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we want to create a new column based on the corresponding elements of 'vectors' `list` to 'dfs', then use `Map` to loop over the two list and `cbind` the vector from 'vectors' with that of 'data.frame' in 'dfs'

```
dfsnew <- Map(cbind, dfs, vec = vectors)
```

---

If we want to create column names as 'vector1', 'vector2', etc, create a named list

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
vectors <- lst(vector1, vector2, vector3)
pmap(list(dfs, vectors, names(vectors)), ~ ..1 %>% 
        mutate(!! ..3 := ..2))
#[[1]]
#  region  x vector1
#1      n 10       1
#2      s 11       2
#3      w 12       3

#[[2]]
#  region  x vector2
#1      n 13       4
#2      s 14       5
#3      w 15       6

#[[3]]
#  region  x vector3
#1      n 16       7
#2      s 17       8
#3      w 18       9
```